# How to write a program that calculate sum of all even numbers under any specific input integer number by using recursion class in java?

Tags: java, recursion

```
//My program can do the calculation only the input number is even.
public static int EvenRecursion(int number){
    if(number == 0)
        return 0;
    return number + EvenRecursion(number-2);
} //question area

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(" ");        
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");         
    int num = input.nextInt();
    int result2 =  EvenRecursion(num);
    System.out.println("Result by using recursion: "+result2);  
}
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? It will work perfectly for the even input.

Comment: @SanketMakani But not for odd input, which is in my opinion why OP asked the question.

Comment: Make it `if(number <= 0)`. EDIT: Make sure you start with an even number. If user enters an odd number, you have to take measures so you start recursion with the appropriate even number.

Comment: For example: `int startVal = input - (input % 2);` (Will subtract 1 if odd, and 0 if even)

Comment: Question is the program can only work if the input number is even,not for odd number, I want the program calculate sum of all even numbers under “any”（even or odd) specific input integer number by using recursion class.

Answer (score 1):

Check for the input user enters. If it is even number just simply pass it as argument of the function and if it is odd number , The highest `even number` which is less than the `entered_number` is `entered_number-1`. So pass this argument `entered_number-1` in function.Try this code!

```
public static int EvenRecursion(int number)
{
    if(number == 0)
        return 0;
    return number + EvenRecursion(number-2);
} //question area

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(" ");        
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");         
    int num = input.nextInt();
    int result2;
    if(num%2==0)                    //If entered number is even pass num in the argument
        result2 =  EvenRecursion(num);
    else                            //If entered number is odd then pass num-1 in the argument
        result2 = EvenRecursion(num-1);

    System.out.println("Result by using recursion: "+result2);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it, if you need explanation let me know:

```
public static int EvenRecursion(int number){

if(number <= 0)
{
      return 0;
}
else if(number%2==0) //if the number is odd you must start with the first even
{
  return EvenRecursion(number-1);
}
else
{
  return EvenRecursion(number-2) + number;  
}   

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.IOException;

    class Calcutate{
      public static int Even_Recursion( int number){
    if(number == 0)
            return 0;
    else
        return number + Even_Recursion(number-2);
}   

public static void main( String []args){
    try{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter your number :");
        int number = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int result;
        if(number%2==0)
            result = Even_Recursion(number);
        else
            result = Even_Recursion(number-1);  

        br.close();
        System.out.println("Result :"+result);
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
        ex.getMessage();
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException ex){
        ex.getMessage();
    }

}
```

}